# Match within string if string part is 31 characters or longer

Tags: regex

I have a long list of strings formatted as follows:

- "astringsmaller alongstringthatisgreaterthan32characterstomatch"
- "alongstringthatisgreaterthan32characterstomatch astringsmaller"
- "astring string alongstringthatisgreaterthan32 598931"

Using regex, how would I match a string where that string is greater than 31 characters using the space a delimiter?

For example, the string below would be "seen" as two parts and the counts would be 14 and 47 thus be a valid match.

- "astringsmaller alongstringthatisgreaterthan32characterstomatch"

Unfortunately, the number of delimiters/spaces are not consistent in position or amount. I also have a bunch of other special characters that would be considered as "delimiters"

```
("!")
("@")
('"')
("#")
("$")
("&")
("'")
("(")
(")")
("*")
("+")
(",")
(".")
("/")
(":")
(";")
("<")
("=")
(">")
("?")
("^")
("`")
("{")
("|")
("}")
("~")
(" ")
("  ")
("“")
("”")
("’")
("%")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate which editor, programming language, file format, or etc you need this for. See also the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, what you want to do is match 31+ characters which are not delimiters:

```
[^!@"#$&'()*+,./:;<=>?^`{|}~ “”’%]{31,}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x3Nm5W/2)

---

Also, instead of using a delimiter "blacklist", you maybe could also maybe only match valid words? (but that depends on your exact use case)

```
\w{31,}
```

*(`\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)*

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lyfYxx/1)

Comment: The curly quotes are not regular ASCII, so you might need to separately tell the engine they are Unicode (or some legacy 8-bit eoncoding, if that's what you're stuck on). Too bad the OP won't reveal which platform or language they're on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand this you want to validate lines if they contain a string that is greater than 31 characters (not containing separator). I would suggest using a lookahead like this:

```
^(?=.*[^!@"#$&'))*+,.\/:;<=>?^`{|}~ “”’%\r\n]{31,}).+$
```

[**Demo**](http://%5E(?=.*[%5E!@%22#$&'))*%20,.%5C/:;%3C=%3E?%5E%60%7B%7C%7D~%20%E2%80%9C%E2%80%9D%E2%80%99%25%5Cr%5Cn]%7B31,%7D).%20$)

Then, you can further process those lines as needed.